# com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection

Tags: android, android-volley

A few months ago I developed an app that uses some REST services from a 3rd party.
I then gave up on that project for the party said the services were going to change. 
But, last week I decided to get back to work and restart from where I stoped.

"OK. Here I go again!" - I said, while started my first debugging section in montgs on that project.
But, for my surprise, this time the app wasn't working anymore.
The services seem to work if I put them in a browser (Chrome and IE) but when I try to use Volley to run then... this is what I get:

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{api.cartolafc.globo.com:443, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=131.0.25.48 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
```

I've searched Stackoverflow upside down but no answer solved my problem.

Now I'm stuck on this hipotesis (due to the message above): is there HTTPS anything to do with that?

The services were already "https".

I'm convicted that the 3rd party changed the structure behind the services because "overhit" on their http webservers was the explanation for the initial barrier they imposed to my use. Since the services still work on the browsers I don't know what I am missing.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the services have been changed by the 3rd party. 
I'm quiting the project again.

Thanks guys.